# How to change mesh uvs in maya script?

Tags: python, model, maya

I have a rigged model in maya and this model uses 2 materials, as well as 2 uv sets. Because materials have just different textures I merged textures into one and also wanted to make those 2 materials into one. The problem is that I have 2 uv sets(1 set is using uvs with textures positions with values 0-1 and secondary too but from other texture).

That what I want to do: multiplicate uv.x from 1st uv set by 0.5, and for second uv set I wanted to change: uv.x * 0.5 + 0.5. So I'll be able to use 1 atlas made from 2 textures and use only 1 material. How can I do this? Can you tell me on which functions in Maya-python should I look at? I've tried to find something n google but havent seen any solution.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [cmds.polyEditUV](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/CommandsPython/polyEditUV.html) command to manipulate the UVs.  The `q=True` flag lets you ask for a value and the `e=True` flag lets you set one. You'll need to explicitly tell the command which uvSet to work with if you have more than one.